# Navigation between two mutually exclusive React views with React Router Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have 2 mutually exclusive views and both of them depend on some `state`.

When an event happens I need to switch from **View1** to **View2** using `react-router-redux`, by pushing a new route. I also need to update `state` to required for **View2** data, for example:

```
push('route-to-view2');
store.dispatch({type: 'state-for-view-2-received', payload: 'state-for-
view-2'});
```

The problem is that these two updates happen not atomically. So there is a moment after the route was pushed, but before the state was dispatched when **View2** is shown with no state (or error is shown in my case).

If I change the order like:

```
store.dispatch({type: 'state-for-view-2-received', payload: 'state-for-view-2'});
push('route-to-view2');
```

the same problem arises as **View1** does not work with the state for **View2**.

So in both cases there is a small flickering possible when the navigation happens.

Is there a way to avoid this problem.

Comment: Can you pl explain "The problem is that these two updates happen not atomically". Are you getting some error?

Comment: Not atomically means that the `route` and `state` updated at different times. When the `route` is pushed React will render View2 (which will show error as it does not have required state), only after that the `state` is updated and View2 renders as it suppose to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-batch-enhancer](https://github.com/abc123s/redux-batch-enhancer). It will batch actions and trigger notification from store to react only when all actions are processed by reducer.

```
import { batchActions } from 'redux-batch-enhancer';

dispatch(batchActions([
  store.dispatch({type: 'state-for-view-2-received', payload: 'state-for-view-2'}),
  push('route-to-view2');
]));
```